# Access the raspberry with the USB cable only

Tags: networking, usb

I would like to know how to access the raspberry pi using only the usb cable used to power it.

Is there a way to setup an IP connection through the micro USB port it like we do with firewire equipment?

The setup I would like to achieve:

- connect the raspberry pi to my laptop with the USB cable.
- connect to all the IP services on the raspberry pi without any other wires.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

No.

The micro USB power connection does not provide any data connection. You could back-power the Pi with one of the other USB data ports, but at the risk of frying your Raspberry Pi. You can read more about this in an article I wrote about [powering a Raspberry Pi](http://alexdglover.com/powering-a-raspberry-pi/).

Additionally, there isn't any way to use IP protocol over USB that I know of. At a minimum, you would need to run an ethernet cord from your laptop to your Raspberry Pi or add a wifi dongle to your raspberry pi in combination with a wireless router.